# jQuery Ajax inside XUL or mozBackgroundRequest?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

Actually, i have 2 questions: Following 2 code snippets works without problem;

First snippet is jQuery ajax request. Even if it is cross-domain request, it works. My first question is, what happened to same origin policy, why is that working?

```
var jsLoader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].
                getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);

    jsLoader.loadSubScript("chrome://yuceel/content/jquery-1.6.2.js");

    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery.post("http://example.com/xMessages/index.php/main/ajax_get_something",
    { "p1":"parameter1","p2":"parameter2"},
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

Second snippet is XMLHttpRequest. I was using that untill now, but i wonder which one has more performance? My application will perform requests each 3 seconds, for small text content. Should I prefer using jQuery Ajax instead of this?

```
postRequest:function(url, params, onload, onerror){
        var xhr = null;
        try {
            xhr = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
            xhr.mozBackgroundRequest = true;
            xhr.onload = function(event) {onload(xhr);}
            xhr.onerror = function(event) {onerror(xhr);}
            xhr.open('POST', url, false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(Server.urlencode(params));
        } catch (e) {
            onerror(xhr);
        }
        return xhr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no same-origin policy for add-ons - they have system privileges and are allowed to use anything.

`jQuery.post()` isn't magic, it is simply a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`. So it will do pretty much the same thing you are doing with `XMLHttpRequest` so the performance is pretty much the same. The only difference is `mozBackgroundRequest` but this merely prevents security dialogs - nothing to do with performance.